# Vagrant Virtualbox Webserver, Cannot access from external network

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualbox

I am having an issue and I am not sure where to go, hopefully you guys can help me out here.

I have a virtual box machine that has a bridged network, therefor the device is on my LAN and there is network connectivity to the device.

I can connect to the web server using my local ip adress 192.168.2.41:25878, however when I try to connect to it with my public IP address x.x.x.x:25878 the web browser is waiting for a connection but it never seems to establish.

Here are my config files for Apache2 / Vagrant

***VagrantFile*** - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7cca95da3cfc22de5333

***Apache2 Site*** - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d60efd938d9d7d7de60e

***Ports.conf*** - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8b0c20a78b36cc5d03b0

The port forwarding is correctly set up on my router. What is really puzzling me, is that I am able to connect to the web server using the local IP address 192.168.2.41:25878, however I cannot access it via the public IP address. The web browser is not rejecting the connection, so I am assuming that I have a config error somewhere, specifically in apache.. The web browser shows a spinning wheel when trying to connect.

I've been trying to solve this issue for almost a week now.. I would appreciate any help that you guys may provide.

Comment: hi! Login into the VM and check if apache run.. And apache log.. Thanks!

Comment: Apache is running, from the information I posted we could see that I was able to connect to the webserver from my local IP.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

So I am not sure why the setup above was not working... I changed from bridged networking to NAT and setup host to guest port forwarding through Vagrant (VirtualBox) and it started working!

I also switched to Nginx instead of using Apache.